# Grails use gsp fragment as html template for javascript function

Tags: javascript, grails, gsp

i trying to handle one to many form mapping on my application.

According to [this post](http://omarello.com/2010/08/grails-one-to-many-dynamic-forms/) i create similar code: however, i don't want to put my html inside javascript and i want to make something reusable, so i created a small taglib for handling one to many association.
This taglib accept as input a gsp fragment path that represents the input field row, something like this:

```
<div class="form-group">
<div class="row row-product-option-values">
    <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-3">
        <g:textField name="product.options[<index>].name" class="form-control"></g:textField>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-8 col-sm-8">
        <g:textField name="product.options[<index>].values" class="form-control"></g:textField>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-1 col-sm-1">
        <a class="btn btn-link" type="button">
            <i class="fa fa-remove"></i>
        </a>
    </div>
</div>
```

inside my taglib i use that fragment for generate the javascript html template with this command:

```
render(template: templatePath).replaceAll('\n', '').encodeAsJavaScript();
```

And now the difficult part: i need to replace  with a js variable that i can increment everytime i add a new input row, but i can't figured out how to do that. At the end of the process i need a string similar to this

```
"<div class=\"form-group\"> <div class=\"row row-product-option-values\"> <div class=\"col-md-3 col-sm-3\"> <input type=\"text\" name=\"product.options[" + childCount +"].name\" class=\"form-control\" value=\"\" id=\"product.options[0].name\" /> </div> <div class=\"col-md-8 col-sm-8\"> <input type=\"text\" name=\"product.options[0].values\" class=\"form-control\" value=\"\" id=\"product.options["+ childCount +"].values\" /> </div> <div class=\"col-md-1 col-sm-1\"> <a class=\"btn btn-link\" type=\"button\"> <i class=\"fa fa-remove\"></i> </a> </div> </div></div>";
```

Someone have an idea how to accomplish this task?

Thanks in advice

Luca

Answer (score 0):

1. **Using AJAX:**

Whenever you add a new row, make an ajax call with your desired inputs to a controller and render the desired template from there.
Now update/append your existing parent div with the result.

2. **Using JavaScript**

During initialization store the html from template to a javascript variable. When ever you add a new row, replace the placeholder index with the current row number.

Comment: Yes, of course using javascript string replace it's a way, however it would be better if there is a better way to do that